# RSA Key ( XML Format ) compatible for .Net

Tags: java, .net, encryption, rsa

How to generate xml based RSA keys ( private ,public )  which should be compatible for .NET environment. I tried phpseclib module in PHP. But it is not compatible for .NET. Please suggest me any way to generate the xml based RSA keys in Java  ?  Actually I am working on linux based system. Using these keys I am going to perform encryption and decryption operation.
Like

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>4hjg1ibWXHIlH...ssmlBfMAListzrgk=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>8QZCtrmJcr9uW7VRex+diH...jLHV5StmuBs1+vZZAQ==</P>
    <Q>8CUvJTv...yeDszMWNCQ==</Q>
    <DP>elh2Nv...cygE3657AQ==</DP>
    <DQ>MBUh5XC...+PfiMfX0EQ==</DQ>
    <InverseQ>oxvsj4WCbQ....LyjggXg==</InverseQ>
    <D>KrhmqzAVasx...uxQ5VGZmZ6yOAE=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that they are validated against different XSDs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no support for this out of the box in Java, but it's still fairly trivial.  First off, you generate an RSA key pair using the JCA `KeyPairGenerator`.

Then, you need to cast the private key to the appropriate interface (we use `RSAPrivateCrtKey` instead of `RSAPrivateKey` so we can access the CRT parts), and using Apache Commons Codec for Base64 encoding.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.genKeyPair();
    RSAPrivateCrtKey privKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

    BigInteger n = privKey.getModulus();
    BigInteger e = privKey.getPublicExponent();
    BigInteger d = privKey.getPrivateExponent();
    BigInteger p = privKey.getPrimeP();
    BigInteger q = privKey.getPrimeQ();
    BigInteger dp = privKey.getPrimeExponentP();
    BigInteger dq = privKey.getPrimeExponentQ();
    BigInteger inverseQ = privKey.getCrtCoefficient(); 

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<RSAKeyValue>\n");
    write(builder, "Modulus", n);
    write(builder, "Exponent", e);
    write(builder, "P", p);
    write(builder, "Q", q);
    write(builder, "DP", dp);
    write(builder, "DQ", dq);
    write(builder, "InverseQ", inverseQ);
    write(builder, "D", d);
    builder.append("</RSAKeyValue>");

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}

private static void write(StringBuilder builder, String tag, BigInteger bigInt) {
    builder.append("\t<");
    builder.append(tag);
    builder.append(">");
    builder.append(encode(bigInt));
    builder.append("</");
    builder.append(tag);
    builder.append(">\n");
}

private static String encode(BigInteger bigInt) {
    return new String(Base64.encodeInteger(bigInt), "ASCII");
}
```

You can use a proper XML API if you're so inclined, but I felt no compelling reason not to use `StringBuilder` in this case.  Also, feel free to inline the `BigInteger` instances.  I declared them as variables to make the mapping between Java methods and XML elements more obvious.

Comment: Did you use Bouncy Castle for the Base64 encoding?

Comment: OK, had already voted up, but the import statement was not present :)

Comment: I did mention in second para though ;)

Comment: Bugger, did not see that. I would go to the optician right away, but it's 23:25 over here :)

Comment: The encode method doesn't seem right to me.  encodeInteger() should be returning an array of bytes, so why are you creating a String from it?  Shouldn't you be base64 encoding the resulting string?

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants do reverse operation - take RSAPrivateCrtKey by xml file, do not forget create instance of BigInteger with positive signum parameter.

```
new BigInteger(1, Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBigInteger));
```

It avoids of potential exception

```
java.security.SignatureException: Could not sign data
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineSign(RSASignature.java:178)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1207)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:579)
    ... more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus
    at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.parseMsg(RSACore.java:214)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.crtCrypt(RSACore.java:166)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSACore.rsa(RSACore.java:122)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineSign(RSASignature.java:175)
    ... 6 more
```