# Convert pem rsa key to xml for C# RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString

Tags: c#, php, xml, rsa

I generating RSA public and private key with PHP:

```
function genKeys($pkey, $skey)
{
    $pkGenerate = openssl_pkey_new(array(
        'private_key_bits' => 2048,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
    ));

    $pkGeneratePrivate = null;
    openssl_pkey_export($pkGenerate, $pkGeneratePrivate);

    $pkGenerateDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkGenerate);
    $pkGeneratePublic  = $pkGenerateDetails['key'];

    openssl_pkey_free($pkGenerate);

    $pkImport        = openssl_pkey_get_private($pkGeneratePrivate);
    $pkImportDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkImport);
    $pkImportPublic  = $pkImportDetails['key'];

    openssl_pkey_free($pkImport);

    $result = (bool) strcmp($pkGeneratePublic, $pkImportPublic);

    if ($result) {
        file_put_contents($pkey, $pkGeneratePrivate);
        file_put_contents($skey, $pkGeneratePublic);
    }

    return $result;

}
```

And I need use PEM file with RSACryptoServiceProvider.

So, how to convert PEM public and private to XML?

Comment: Can you explain what the reason to use `strcmp` in your question is? When I run your code, `$pkGeneratePrivate` and `$pkGeneratePublic` are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ :

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('...');

echo $rsa->getPrivateKey(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a little late, I had problems to understand what you're looking for exactly and could decipher it now.

.Net in *RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString* uses an XML key format similar to [the one from XKMS 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xkms2/#XKMS_2_0_Section_8_2) just with a different document element.

The openssl extension in PHP doesn't offer a function to create it directly, however with the help of the [`openssl_pkey_get_details()` function](http://php.net/openssl_pkey_get_details) you can obtain all details of the RSA key you need to create the XML file. Then it's pretty straight forward:

```
$rsa = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkGenerate)['rsa'];

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<RSAKeyValue/>"); // Use <RSAKeyPair/> for XKMS 2.0

// .Net / XKMS openssl RSA indecies to XML element names mappings
$map = ["n"    => "Modulus", "e"    => "Exponent", "p"    => "P",        "q"    => "Q",
        "dmp1" => "DP",      "dmq1" => "DQ",       "iqmp" => "InverseQ", "d"    => "D",];

foreach ($map as $key => $element) {
    $xml->addChild($element, base64_encode($rsa[$key]));
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

This example continues after your key generation which you have the resource in the `$pkGenerate` variable and the "stores" it to stdout (for demonstration purposes). You can also store it to file:

```
$xml->asXML('/path/to/file');
```

or assing it to a variable:

```
$xmlString = $xml->asXML();
```

So technically if you're using the openssl extension, you don't need to add full *phpseclib* just to create the XML.

Related material:

- [RSA Key ( XML Format ) compatible for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12512455/367456) (Java)
- [Key File Encoding - RSA Key Formats](http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html)
- [What is a Pem file and how does it differ from other OpenSSL Generated Key File Formats?](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/69499)